# Getting this error in cloudwatch : exec /usr/bin/java: exec format error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, java-17

I am unable to understand what mistake I am doing. Please look at this and help.
I have chosen Linux family operating system in task definiton. Getting this error. Please take a look into below screenshots.

This is the cloud watch error I am getting when I run the task definition in ECS fargate cluster.
[image: This is the cloud watch error]

This is the Dockerfile in the springboot project. I am running
[image: Dockerfile of the springboot project]

This is the environment config of my code build pipeline.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are doing one of two things:

- Building the docker image on an X86 computer (like a standard Intel or AMD PC), pushing it to ECR, and then deploying it to a Graviton Fargate instance.
- Building the docker image on an M1 Mac, or other ARM based computer, pushing it to ECR, and then deploying it to a standard Fargate instance.

In either case, the CPU architecture of your build machine does not match the CPU architecture of your deployment environment.

Comment: First thing, since we are building the images in the aws code build how do my machine comes into this picture. And can u pls suggest the solution ?

Comment: I didn't notice you were using CodeBuild. So CodeBuild is the machine that needs to match your deployment environment. You need to decide if you are going to deploy to standard, or Graviton Fargate instances, and then select either standard, or ARM for your CodeBuiild compute type.

Comment: M1 mac was the issue for me. Thanks @MarkB

Answer (score 0):

Previously, I was getting this error bcz in Code Build pipeline I chose Operating System as Amazon Linux 2, Run time as Standard. Image as aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-aarch64-standard:3.0

How I resolved this issue.
Very interesting, just did trial and error by selecting the images one by one and build the image.

Ultimately for image "aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:5.0" . It actually worked.
[image]

For more information visit this aws documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html